# Create React Template in visual studio 2022 gives error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2022

When i try to create react project in vs2022 it gives me this error (final stage after npm start):

[image]

if i go to temp project build in drive C it have all file gathered successfully :

[image]

but the final folder is empty and nothing moved from temp folder :

[image]

Edit : After Some trial and error ive find out that its possible to make solution only in drive that u have windows temp folder and not on ther partition.why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the project don't select the option of Place the solution and project in the same directory and the project will be created in directory you want.